# How to color utf char font with itextsharp in vb, c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, colors, itext

I have a code that writes a triangle char inside a table using itextsharp in visual studio (it could be vb or c#).
To do so I am using threbuchet font which contains it. It works fine, but I would like to colour the triangle to red. When trying to do so using  `iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont` (which I think is good to get color), no symbol at all is written to pdf.

Is there other way to colour a font  inside `New iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 8)`?

this is the code

```
' table
Dim nTbl As PdfPTable = New PdfPTable(2)
nTbl.HorizontalAlignment = PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER
nTbl.SetTotalWidth({40, 60})

' this works and adds the triangle char
Dim FONT As String = "fonts\trebucbd.ttf"
Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
Cell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Δ", New iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 8)))
Cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1
Cell.VerticalAlignment = 1
nTbl.AddCell(Cell) 

' this does not work, when trying to colour triangle 
Cell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Δ", iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("fonts\trebucbd.ttf", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, New iTextSharp.text.Color(128, 0, 0))))
Cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1
Cell.VerticalAlignment = 1
nTbl.AddCell(Cell)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your `BaseFont.CreateFont()` you are explicitly saying to embed but in your `FontFactory.GetFont()` you are relying on system defaults which is to not embed. You need to use the longer version of the `GetFont()` method which specifies embedding.

It looks like you're using the 4.1.6 version which I don't have laying around but this should be pretty much the same except for the last parameter:

```
iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 20, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.RED)
```

Also, `GetFont()` is intended to take a font name, not a path, although if that name lookup fails it does still restort to calling `BaseFont.Create()` but I'm not sure if you should rely on that. Instead, you should pre-register your fonts:

```
iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.Register(FONT, "Treb")
```

Then you can use `GetFont()` with the alias.

```
iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Treb", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 20, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.RED)
```

The advantage of doing this is that if for some reason your font file gets renamed or deleted,  `FontFactory.Register()` will throw an exception whereas `FontFactory.GetFont()` will silently fail with a fallback font. The silent fallback sounds nice but you also might spend hours troubleshooting something that's an easy fix.

Comment: I have trebuchet font on "fonts" folder do I need to tell where it is?

Comment: iText will not automatically look for fonts, you have to tell it where to look. Alternatively you can also register an entire folder using `FontFactory.RegisterDirectory()`. Depending on the number of fonts in that folder this might slow your program down.